# Native module RNGoogleSignin tried to override RNGoogleSigninModule error

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am implementing google authentication in React Native but even after following all the steps I keep getting the same error:

> Native module RNGoogleSignin tried to override RNGoogleSigninModule
>   error

There is no duplicate in the code! I have no idea why it keeps showing this error after I try to run it.

This is how I am importing:

```
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;
```

And this is how I am adding it in the getPackages()

```
packages.add(new RNGoogleSigninPackage());
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 19):

In my case it was due to very stupid problem did by myself.

I had 2 versions of react native google sigin. I installed with these commands

```
yarn add @react-native-community/google-signin
yarn add react-native-google-signin
```

After uninstalling react-native-google-sigin my problem got solved.I know this is old but might be worthy for someone.

Comment: Omg you're not alone! I did the exact stupid thing and i got the same error and thank you for this answer!!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply!! I wasted 4 hours debugging this issue.

Comment: This replay solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

What version of React Native are you on?

If you're on 0.60 or later, you shouldn't need to do `packages.add(new RNGoogleSigninPackage());` , since the library is auto-linked.

If you NEED to add that library in the MainApplication's `getPackages()` (maybe because you're instantiating the package with a key, or you have issues with auto-linking), you can do so. You can stop packages from being auto-linkd by adding them to the list of dependencies, in the file named `react-native.config.js` in the root of your project (if you don't have it, you should create it).

If you want to disable auto-linking for `react-native-google-signin` , your `react-native.config.js` should look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-google-signin': {
      platforms: {
        android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
      },
    },

  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens when you installed **@react-native-community/google-signin** and **@react-native-google-signin/google-signin**, Make sure to uninstall one of them by running the commands below:

**npm uninstall @react-native-google-signin/google-signin.**

Retry again after uninstalling one of this package

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm this is caused by duplicate google-sign-in and google auth duplicated in package.json

The cause of this is autolinking just remove any duplicates in your package.json